# Finding all roots of a complex polynomial with SymPy

Tags: python, math, polynomial-math, sympy

I'm trying to symbolically solve a polynomial with complex numbers and their conjugates with SymPy. I think I've come a long way, but `solve` does not give me any solutions although the polynomial is solveable.

```
from sympy import *

# set up symbols
a, b = symbols("a b", real=True)
t = a+I*b
T = functions.conjugate(t)

# set up polynomial
a1=0.005+I*0.0009
a2=0.9+I*-0.9
a3=0.4+I*0.5
a4=8+I*-80
a5=284+I*-1.5
a6=27100+I*-11500
poly=t**2 * T * a1 + t * T * a2 + t**2 * a3 + T * a4 + t * a5 + a6

# Trying to solve symbolically...
solve([re(poly), im(poly)], a, b)
#     Output: []

# Solving numerically works, but only finds one solution...
nsolve((re(poly), im(poly)), (a, b), (0, 0))
#     Output: matrix(
#             [['-137.962596090596'],
#              ['52.6296963395752']])

# verify with two solutions obtained in Maxima
poly.subs({a:-137.9625935162095, b:52.6296992481203}).n()
#     Output: 0.000540354631040322 + 0.00054727003909351*I
poly.subs({a:-332.6474382554614+I*-185.9848818313149, b:258.0065640091016+I*-272.3344263478699}).n()
#     Output: -6.55448222470652e-12 - 1.41238056784605e-12*I
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is indeed strange. Just a question to be sure: given that the value after the sobstitution of the first one is far from zero, could it be that the poly cannot be solve and maxima gave you a numeric approximation? (I don't know maxima very well, so I don't really konw how it behave)

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri It could well be that Maxima gave me a numeric approximation, but in its output it does not mention it. I'm no Maxima expert, either :-( Anyway, it would be fine if SymPy would give the solutions that Maxima gave, even if they are just numeric approximations.

Comment: I tried a little to work with this kind of equations and looks like the problem is in the sympy solve mechanism that doesn't play well with the complex numbers. I'm trying to find out if we missed some condition that is needed to make it work...

Comment: This does not look like a polynomial to me. A polynomial has constant coefficients of the type `a_0 z^0 + a_1 z^1 + ...` What you have are terms like `a_1 z^2 z*` i.e. the `a1` term is multiplied by it's complex conj. If you had a polynomial mpmath from sympy should work great http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/polynomials.html

Comment: It seems that SymPy just can't solve this, but even if it could, it wouldn't give you those results from Maxima, because you set `a` and `b` to be real, so `solve()` would only give you values of `a` and `b` that are real.

Comment: I opened SymPy issue https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3735 for this. Hopefully we will get it fixed.

Comment: @asmeurer Thanks for opening the bug. You're obviously right, using the complex solutions of Maxima did not make any sense. I should have inserted them into t, and store the resulting real part in a and the complex part in b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem could be that your coefficients contain floating point numbers. This often does not work with symbolic software.

Using f=10000*simplify(re(poly)) and g=10000*simplify(im(poly)) and editing the results gives polynomials with integer coefficients. The CAS (Magma in my case) then can produce a triangular representation of the ideal of f and g, which is given as the polynomials

```
a - 2483798807340123709959247/13545514719183259347425004828125*b^4
  + 66732206412048596386372283/541820588767330373897000193125*b^3 
  - 3849759933277117021785191063/86691294202772859823520030900*b^2
  + 9245906471290310401430681453/1733825884055457196470400618*b
  - 31414499425567273751868164900/866912942027728598235200309,

b^5 - 189465979625/206648369*b^4 
    + 330827538698125/826593476*b^3
    - 17645868534640625/206648369*b^2 
    + 1724106750659765625/206648369*b
    - 52548859891484375000/206648369
```

which tells us that 5 solutions exist. The numerical solutions for the second polynomial are

```
174.10461010682254746847015187264557067610513554291323564643772 
 + 63.402741884833821878468926640811609033267039765104756747285816*i

174.104610106822547468470151872645570676105135542913235646437738
 - 63.402741884833821878468926640811609033267039765104756747285804*i

258.006564009101655109715962546854008929462784282347754971379392
  + 272.334426347869856080204881056671278679761260094680345276069337*i

258.006564009101655109715962546854008929462784282347754971379382
 - 272.334426347869856080204881056671278679761260094680345276069359*i

52.62969633957523864698147679803879873180829265956656342643376
```

resulting in exactly one real solution. The numerical result of sympy was correct and complete.